# Does booking directly from an airline improve customer service in resolving problems?

Tags: air-travel, airlines, bookings, united-airlines, air-canada

In 2012 I used a third-party site to book international flights on Air Canada and had many problems resulting from missed connections (their fault).  Ultimately I got no compensation and at one point one of their reps said to me something like "well what do you expect; you didn't buy the ticket from us directly so we can't do much to help you".

I've just returned from an international trip booked directly from United.  When one connection was at risk (their fault), they sent email saying that if we did in fact miss that plane we now had reserved spots on the next flight.  We never contacted them (we were busy sprinting through an airport); they initiated that.

Is the difference in these outcomes the direct ticket purchase, or is it the different airlines?  (Maybe United's customer service is just way better than Air Canada's?)  We also bought travel insurance this time (didn't know to do that the first time), but since we never invoked it I'm not sure that matters.

I'm trying to figure out if the lesson here is "buy direct from the airline" or "fly United (where possible)".  I don't have the fortitude (or travel frequency) to determine this experimentally, e.g. by buying a ticket directly from Air Canada to see what happens.

Comment: I guess you're referring to: http://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/8248/how-do-i-get-compensation-for-messed-up-flights

Comment: @Karlson yup.  Wasn't sure if I should link to that in the question.

Comment: It's always better to have a more complete picture.

Comment: Re your edit, I was really trying to focus specifically on the customer-service aspect.  I'm not looking for answers about, say, financial benefits like bonus miles for buying direct.

Comment: Not sure how one would make this determination if it is at all possible but there is a similar discussion on [TripAdvisor](http://www.tripadvisor.com/ShowTopic-g1-i10702-k5667222-Booking_on_Airline_Site_vs_Expedia_or_other_3rd_party-Air_Travel.html)

Comment: From a quick scan of your other question and the forum posts I couldn't see whether you had bought your ticket from another Star Alliance member, a holiday/travel agent, or a comparison site. Could you clarify? It may have a bearing on the answer.

Comment: I bought the Air Canada ticket through a link on Kayak, but it wasn't from Air Canada directly.  So some third-party web-based agent but I no longer remember the details (can look up later).  We bought the United tickets through United's web site.  (Sorry, didn't mean to leave out important info -- just didn't know what was important!)

Comment: @MonicaCellio do you have status with either AC or UA? This can make a huge difference, and if you're making international flights reasonably often, you might have status, so it's worth mentioning whether you do or not.

Comment: I don't have status with any airline, no.  Or at least I've done nothing to seek it; I assume it doesn't happen automatically.  I fly pretty infrequently.

Comment: One man's opinion, it's always better to book directly with an airline.  There are many advantages.  I love expedia, but it's plane better to book direct. These days it is rarely more expensive to book direct.

Comment: Depends on your "problem" ...

Comment: The very nature of the question will only offer opinions based on biased experiences as answers. The "buy direct from the airline (advantages/disadvantages)" aspect would be more suited as a question that could be answered. I have booked and flown thousands of flights in my life, but it would never have occurred to me not to book as closely as possible with the operating carrier, ever. What you might save on airfare through third-party ticketing vendors, you will almost always lose in service dispute cases due to the prolonged value chain and the resulting increased moral hazard situations.

Answer (score 4):

While it varies from airline to airline, certainly booking through the airline, or a reputable travel agent helps. As a travel coach, if the prices are the same I always send my clients through the airline, because if something goes wrong with the reservation, or in the booking process the airline is much more likely to help rather than route you through what ever online travel agency you bought your ticket from. Some airlines will help no matter what, but in my experience it is better to either book with the airline, or at least as directly as you can.
Some sources:
http://www.moneytalksnews.com/2012/01/06/avoiding-5-common-issues-with-travel-sites/2/
http://elliott.org/the-navigator/a-problem-with-your-reservation-maybe-your-travel-agency-should-pay/
http://www.forbes.com/sites/larrymagid/2013/04/13/why-i-hate-travel-agencies/

Comment: Any facts to back this up?

Comment: Hi Karlson - you're right to ask for facts, but it's one of those questions that really comes down to experience.  I surely agree that it's plain better to use the direct booking process.