# What to do if airline persistently doesn't respond to complaint?

Tags: airlines, refunds, lufthansa, missed-flights

I had a problem with my Lufthansa flights, in my opinion that was completely the airline's fault. At the desk during the day of flights, they (naturally) didn't give me any proper response, just a card with information on where to send complaints. I decided to pursue that, sent a refund request to the email address they had on the card. After to weeks of waiting without a single response apart from the automatically generated "we got your message, this is your issue number, we'll contact you as soon as possible", I decided to send another message to them using the complaint form on their website. I even included the issue number and mentioned that I had been waiting two weeks already. I got another similar automatically generated response right away, then nothing else for another three weeks.

What should I do now? I really don't feel like calling them, as that won't take me anywhere. Is there a place I can complain about an airline apart from suing them? Obviously I'm not looking for any costly ways of pursuing action, I just want to get my well-deserved response.

My situation is similar to [this question](https://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/8248/how-do-i-get-compensation-for-messed-up-flights), where the author was looking to get compensation because of messed up flights. I may or may not be eligible for a compensation, but not getting a response is simply not acceptable.

Comment: Honestly, every time I've had a problem like this, I've tweeted about it and tagged in their social media account. Suddenly get very prompt service (they don't seem to like it public). Apart from Jetstar who cancelled my flight without warning, so I had to buy a more expensive flight with Virgin.  Tweeted this and Jetstar just responded "have a good flight".  But others have been very keen to engage on social media, even after no response via email. I've heard similar things about their facebook pages, although I prefer twitter (they can't delete my tweets!)

Comment: Social media is the answer. Airlines do not guarantee that their flights will be on schedule.

Comment: It is entirely possible that your issue is not the fault of the airline nor something you are owed any special treatment, hence the reason they haven't given you the satisfaction you think you deserve.  And as you have not included those details, it is hard for anyone to accurately tell you who to contact, other than Mark's shotgun approach.

Comment: Actually @Mark Mayo's approach is a valid response, would you mind changing it to an answer?

Comment: @Tom : Wether or not the issue is the fault of the airline, there is absolutely no justification to NOT being answered.

Answer (score 4):

If you live in Germany, you might want to contact the SÖP (mediation committee for public transport in Germany). You could also contact the national aviation authorities (in Germany it would be the Bundesluftfahrtamt).